# What replaces mysql-*-5.6?

Tags: raspberry-pi, mysql, mariadb

I'm following [these instructions](https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Build_from_Source) to get MythTV set up on a Raspberry Pi 3. One of the steps is to install mysql (both server and client):

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6 ntp libicu55 libqt5sql5-mysql mysql-client-5.6
```

However, this fails with:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-client-5.6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mariadb-server-core-10.0 mariadb-client-5.5 mariadb-client-10.0

Package mysql-server-5.6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  mariadb-server-5.5 mariadb-server-10.0

E: Package 'mysql-server-5.6' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libicu55
E: Package 'mysql-client-5.6' has no installation candidate
```

If I'm to trust what the output tells me, I can safely install mariadb instead of mysql and everything will work fine (I don't know how safe that assumption is). But even so, it's not clear to me which version of mariadb to install. There is no corresponding 5.6, so does that mean I need 10? That seems like a big jump and I'm concerned I may end up with something that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MariaDB is a fork of MySQL, done by the original developers of MySQL when MySQL was acquired by Oracle. It's the standard RDBMS provided in most modern distributions, for instance RHEL/CentOS 7.

Version 10.0 is simply the version successive to 5.5. The developers of MariaDB wanted to do a clean start and differentiate themselves clearly from the original project.

MariaDB is designed to be MySQL-compatible and uses the same names for the executables (`mysql`, `mysqldump`, `mysql_upgrade`, etc). You can safely install it.

Comment: OK, thanks. So I should install version 10 then, right?

Comment: Yes, install 10.0 which seems to be the latest version available on your system.